v$session vs sys.v_$session
TLDR; Is it safe to change GRANT SELECT ON V$SESSION TO FOOBAR_ADMIN to GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_$SESSION TO FOOBAR_ADMIN and have FOOBAR_ADMIN work exactly the same?  (Note, the question isn't whether the granter is able to do it, assume they can, but rather are both statements functionally equivalent from the grantees perspective)
Our application in production connects to Oracle ATP and does GRANT SELECT ON V$SESSION TO FOOBAR_ADMIN.  Our application is also tested locally using a docker database and the same grant fails there
I narrowed down the problem to the fact that production connects to ATP as ADMIN whereas our tests connect to the docker database as SYS.  Thus V$SESSION resolves to ADMIN.V$SESSION in production (which is a view that already exists there) whereas in test it resolves to SYS.V$SESSION (which is . . . I really don't know, some sort of virtual table which does not support the grant)
I am new to Oracle and while I can find plenty of articles on how to use v$session view/table to kill stuck sessions, I can't find any tangible information about what it actually is or the relationship between SYS.V$SESSION, SYS.V_$SESSION, and USER.V$SESSION
My thought is that we can/should use GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_$SESSION TO FOOBAR_ADMIN (which is the view in SYS that maps to SYS.V$SESSION).  This is unambiguous and quick testing shows that it works and allows the grantee to do select * from v$session but I am afraid to change our production stuff to simplify our test environment without knowing exactly what I am doing

non-Autonomous DB:
V$SESSION is a public synonym for V_$SESSION.
V_$SESSION is a view owned by SYS.
USER.V$SESSION normally does not exist.
When granting privileges on such views, the privileges need to be granted on the view and not the synonym.
GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_$SESSION TO FOOBAR_ADMIN is correct.
GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V$SESSION TO FOOBAR_ADMIN is incorrect.
Autonomous DB:
Granting on V$SESSION only works for you, because you use ATP where general rules had to be worked around. ADMIN.V$SESSION is an object that exists only in ATP and its purpose is to eliminate the need for granting privileges to SYS-owned objects directly, because you don't get full access in an Autonomous DB.
